# Compile MASM file with C++ extern references

Tags: c++, linux, x86, g++, masm

I'm trying to compile in linux a MASM file that's have some "extern" variables but I'm not able to link the ".o" files together.
I mean I have a ".cpp" file with some "extern" variables and function on it and then I have a ".asm" file with some "extern" variables on it.
The files are these:

IntegersExploration.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" char GlChar = 10;
extern "C" short GlShort = 20;
extern "C" int GlInt = 30;
extern "C" long long GlLongLong = 0x000000000FFFFFFFF;

extern "C" void IntegerAddition(char a, short b, int c, long long d);

int main(){
    IntegerAddition(3, 5, -37, 11);
    
    printf("int value %d\n", GlInt);

    return 0x0;
}
```

IntegersEx.asm:

```
.386
.model flat, c

extern GlChar:byte
extern GlShort:word
extern GlInt:dword
extern GlLongLong:qword

.code

IntegerAddition proc
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp

; Compute GlChar += a       (char = byte = 8 bit            =>  I use AL)
    mov al,[ebp + 8]
    add [GlChar],al

;Compute GlShort += b       (short = word = 16 bit          =>  I use AX)
    mov ax,[ebp + 12]
    add [GlShort],ax

;Compute GlInt += c         (int = dword = 32 bit           =>  I use EAX)
    mov eax,[ebp + 16]
    add [GlInt],eax

;Compute GlLongLong += d    (long long = qword = 64 bit     =>  I use EAX + EDX)
    mov eax,[ebp + 20]
    mov edx,[ebp + 24]
    add dword ptr[GlLongLong],eax
    adc dword ptr[GlLongLong],edx

    pop ebp
    ret

IntegerAddition endp
                end
```

I am compiling "IntegersExploration.cpp" with:

```
g++ -Wall -c IntegersExploration.cpp
```

And I'm compiling "IntegersEx.asm" with:

```
jwasm -coff IntegersEx.asm
```

But when I link the 2 ".o" objects I get using:

```
g++ -m32 IntegersExploration.o IntegersEx.o
```

I get the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `IntegersExploration.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: IntegersEx.o:IntegersEx.asm:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `_GlChar'
/usr/bin/ld: IntegersEx.o:IntegersEx.asm:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `_GlShort'
/usr/bin/ld: IntegersEx.o:IntegersEx.asm:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `_GlInt'
/usr/bin/ld: IntegersEx.o:IntegersEx.asm:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `_GlLongLong'
/usr/bin/ld: IntegersEx.o:IntegersEx.asm:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `_GlLongLong'
/usr/bin/ld: IntegersExploration.o: in function `main':
IntegersExploration.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `IntegerAddition'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It's like the "asm" file doesn't link properly the extern variables to the "cpp" file. How can I solve this?

Thank you very much!
Have a nice coding!

Comment: You appear to be compiling your c++ code as x86-64, try adding -m32 to your g++ command. (or use a 32-bit compiler build, maybe i686-pc-linux-gcc). Also, add an _ to the extern symbol names in the .asm file, the names in the asm must match how the compiler decorates them.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir -m32 on the compilation of the ".cpp" file? If I had it I get the same error when I link them together. Also by adding the _ I get the same error but with a "_" more in the errors.

Comment: Can you use x86-64 asm?

Comment: @Eljay I'm doing exercises on MASM so I'd like to compile using MASM

Comment: MASM supports x86-64.

Comment: @Eljay I think I'm not understanding what you're trying to say. Do you mean to use x64 registers or what? I already tryed to compile with MASM.EXE and it doesn't work too.

Comment: I'm saying that `i386` ≠ `x86-64`.  Rather than trying to get the C++ to compile as `i386`, you could use `x86-64` asm.  As an alternative.

Comment: @Eljay So I should just remove the ".386" directive? Or should I change something else?

Comment: You'd change the `IntegersEx.asm` to be x86-64 assembly.  It's a different assembly, like how 68000 is different from PowerPC is different from ARM is different from 6502.

Comment: @Eljay But, as I said before, I'm trying to do exercises in this kind of assembly (masm) not in asm. I just have the problem of linking the extern variables/functions and I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: First of all are you sure that `g++ -m32 -Wall -c IntegersExploration.cpp` produced the exact same result? I highly doubt that. It may have given errors but not the exact same ones. Without the `-m32` it generated x86-64 code and then tried to link 32 and 64-bit objects. The question I have when you use `-m32` on all `g++` commands is what are the exact errors produced. There may be errors but they won't be the same.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes there are a little different. I mean the errors are the same of the one I wrote on the question but without the first error "/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `IntegersExploration.o' is incompatible with i386 output".
I still have the errors:
/usr/bin/ld: IntegersEx.o:IntegersEx.asm:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `__GlChar'
/usr/bin/ld: IntegersEx.o:IntegersEx.asm:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `__GlShort' ecc.. ecc..
So he doesn't link correctly the extern variables and function

Comment: Did you remember to add an _ to the extern symbol names in the .asm file?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir I tryed to add an "\_" in the extern variables, but if I do so I get the same error with two "\_\_" before the variables names instead of just one "\_" :/
/usr/bin/ld: IntegersEx.o:IntegersEx.asm:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `__GlChar'
/usr/bin/ld: IntegersEx.o:IntegersEx.asm:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `__GlShort'
/usr/bin/ld: IntegersEx.o:IntegersEx.asm:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `__GlInt'
/usr/bin/ld: IntegersEx.o:IntegersEx.asm:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `__GlLongLong'....

Comment: No, don't add the _ in the .cpp file, only the .asm.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Yes I tryed to add it in the asm and I get this error.
Anyway if I compile this with the same compiler options of jwasm and g++ on Windows 7 It get linked together right, if I try on Linux I get those errors :/

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm using Jwasm and g++ :/ Honestly Idk what to use to compile this on linux. I can compile the files so I though it was right xD On windows it works, on Linux I get those references errors :/

Comment: Naming convention on Linux is different (In Linux programs/objects it doesn't use `_`  like on Windows) and the calling convention for functions is different. Are you trying to compile/link a program that runs on Linux or are you trying to create a Windows program using Linux tools and are intending to run the result as a Windows program?

Comment: Mh I'm following some exercises I found in MASM that are done in VisualStudio but I'd like, if possibile, to do it on linux. I'm new in MASM so I'm figuring it out xD Anyway I'm trying to compile/link the code I wrote above that uses MASM (so for Windows if I'm right) on Linux using jwasm and g++. But I don't know if it's possible at this point :/
I mean, if I use MASM on a C++ program it automatically become a program that runs as a Window program right?

Comment: Miscorosft's MASM only targets windows programs. It happens to be JWASM can target Windows and Linux if you want to. You aren't actually using MASM/JWASM on a C++ program, you are assembling an ASM file to an object file (and in this case Windows/COFF) that will be linked into a program.

Comment: It is in fact possible though to use Linux tools on Linux to create Windows programs. The resulting program would need an emulator like Wine to run (as it is Windows program). If you are using Ubuntu you might be able to do `sudo apt-get install mingw-w64` and then instead of using `g++` you'd use `i686-w64-mingw32-g++` to create 32-bit Windows objects and executable. This is called cross compilation. Using Linux to create Windows programs

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you so much. I need to use mingw with some arguments or alone?

Comment: In your case everywhere you are using `g++` you replace it with `i686-w64-mingw32-g++` to create 32-bit Windows programs and objects. This particular version of g++ (and the linker) understand Windows COFF objects used in 32-bit Windows applications and generates code and objects for it. In fact you will find that all the Windows cross compile tools start with `i686-w64-mingw32-`

Comment: In Ubuntu Linux after using `sudo apt-get...` as I mentioned earlier, afterwards if you type `i686-w64-mingw32-` and then hit the TAB key the auto completion should show you a list of all the win32 specific cross compiler tools.

Comment: Using `i686-w64-mingw32-g++` all the options you were using on Windows using MinGW tools remain the same although you can drop the `-m32` if you want since the i686 version default to generating 32-bit Windows objects/programs

Comment: If you make Windows executables, you'll need WINE or something to run them on Linux, so debugging your code with GDB might be more complicated.  Since your program would be running under WINE, not as the top-level executable of a process.  Being able to use a debugger is essential; without that you'd be wasting tons of time.

Comment: @PeterCordes : While there are a few more steps to debugging with Wine it is possible because there is also a MinGW cross debugger which can be used to debug programs running in a Wine session from the Linux console. On more recent versions of Ubuntu for example you can install the GDB cross debug package `gdb-mingw-w64` . There are some tutorials online showing how this works as well.

Comment: @MichaelPetch If I try to compile IntegersExploration.cpp with mingw with this command:
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ IntegersExploration.cpp
I get this error:
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/cc94OtiU.o:IntegersExploration.cpp:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `IntegerAddition'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.

Comment: You are supposed to use the same options you used in Windows. You are missing the `-c` option to compile that CPP file to an object rather than an executable. Run all the same commands replacing g++ with `i686-w64-mingw32-g++` and keep all the options/parameters the same.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Ok thanks I compiled it, but if I run it with wine I get the error: 0024:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\z3r0\\Scrivania\\All\\Programming\\Assembly\\MASM\\IntegersExploration\\a.exe") not found
0024:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\z3r0\\Scrivania\\All\\Programming\\Assembly\\MASM\\IntegersExploration\\a.exe") not found
0024:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"Z:\\home\\z3r0\\Scrivania\\All\\Programming\\Assembly\\MASM\\IntegersExploration\\a.exe" failed, status c00001

Comment: @MichaelPetch and if I try to run the a.exe file on windows 7 I also get an error about libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll missing :/

Comment: Try adding the option `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++`  to thr g++ options. See what happens.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Wow Working! Thank you so much you are really good at this!